# Passing extended data type value between 2 forms

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

Scenario:
I've created two simple forms. The Form1 is a simple StringEdit control with a button. The Form2 is a set of different controls and buttons and Form2 opens after clicking the button of the Form1.

What I need:
What I need is the Form2 initialized with the value set in the StringEdit control of the Form1.

I tried to do it assigning DataSource and DataField to the StrinEdit control and it worked:

```
void clicked()
{

Args args;
FormRun formRun;
;
args = new Args();
args = element.args();
args.name(formStr(Form3));
args.record(SMAServiceOrderTable);

formRun = ClassFactory.formRunClass(args);
formRun.init();
formRun.run();
formRun.wait();

super();
}


public void init()
{
SMAServiceOrderTable serviceordertable;
super();
serviceordertable = element.args().record();
}
```

But this works when a DataSource and a DataField is associated to the StringEdit. Could someone explain me how should I build it to pass the value of Form1 to Form2 when is an ExtendedDataType?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you've been able to use `args.record()` to pass the record to the called object (Form2), you can also use `args.parm()` to pass a string value, `args.parmEnum()` and `args.parmEnumType()` to pass an enum value, or `args.parmObject()` to pass any object. You can also use `args.caller(element)` so that Form2 can have access to Form1 methods.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1, use args.caller(element) to form1 instance and in Form1 create a method to return value of string field it will work. 
Option 2 is to override button click method to open Form2 through code and that time you can pass arguments to form. 
Also refer this blog https://calebmsdax.wordpress.com/2013/02/22/passing-parameters-between-forms-in-ax/